# live search city?

Tags: php, ios, performance, geolocation

I'm working on a iPhone-application, and within one section the user should be able to search for cities. I would like to do it like the weather app is working on the iPhone, where user can start type and get a response right away with "matching" city names. For each city in the result I need to get; name of the city, county/state, country, longitude, and latitude.

1. Are there any free API for this, that you can use in a commercial iphone-application (that might cost money)?
2. What would be the best way to actually perform the live-search? I means of, to not put to much pressure on the server.. If the user types 2 characters, and the continue to type one more, and so on, then that will be a lot of requests to the server? (im thinking of having a "proxy" script on my server that calls the API for geo-info...

Thanx

Comment: It would be best if you used your own weather data set.  You don't want people trying to get to a city that you don't have data for, yes?  If you don't have this data at all, check the USPS data.  https://www.usps.com/business/address-information-systems.htm

Comment: I'm not following? Use my own weather data set, what do you mean by that?

Comment: You have weather data for cities, yes?  Therefore, you know what these cities are, right?  Even if you're just using some API to get weather data, you should use that API provider's data set for cities.  If they do not have one, USPS data is available for the US.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. The problem is tho that these weather APIs are a little bit different how they work. Some need only the city name and country, some other need city name, county/state name, and country.
And also, most of the time the user will type say "Paris", and not "Paris,France". The city might exist in more than one country. And I want the user be able to search for just "Paris" and get results for both US (for example) and France, and then use the information for each result to build up a VO-object that contains everything I need, and THEN call the weather API with all info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [free database from MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities). It contains the following fields:

- Country Code
- ASCII City Name
- City Name
- Region
- Population
- Latitude
- Longitude

I would suggest that the best thing to do is load this into your own database, and provide a simple web service for lookups, as  you have proposed.  If you put a proper index on your database, lookups will be fairly fast.  It's small enough that you could even load the whole table into memory.